# Abrir PDF con Axacropdf1 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, archivo, pdf

Estoy programando con VB.net y necesito abrir un pdf que está en la carpeta de Resources del proyecto usando una ruta genérica y con AxAcroPDF1. Me pasa que mover el proyecto no abrirá el pdf. Mí código es:

```
Dim OFD como nuevo OpenFileDialog
OFD.FileName = "D:\Proyecto\Form\Resources\File.pdf"

AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile (OFD.FileName)
```

Necesito saber como reemplazar `"D:\Proyecto\Form\Resources\File.pdf"`
Gracias.

Comment: de casualidad el filename no debe ir sin espacios???

Comment: si, al convertirlo a código me puso los espacios, de todas formas ya lo resolví y lo coloqué en una respuesta. Gracias!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Gracias por tu ayuda! lo resolví de la siguiente forma y funciona.

Dim ejecutarrutacompleta = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.Length - 10, My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.Length)

```
Dim RutaDeaplicacion As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, ejecutarrutacompleta)
Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
OFD.FileName = RutaDeaplicacion & "\Resources\File.pdf"
AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile(OFD.FileName)
```

Comment: Este codigo no tiene mucho sentido.. .para que instancias un OFD, si luego no lo usas para nada?

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas utilizar un explorador de directorio, puedes darle la opción al usuario que seleccione el archivo, si esto es necesario para tu programa te paso un codigo ejemplo :

```
   Dim rutaDefault = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim fileDefault = "nombrearchivo.pdf"

    Dim abrir As New OpenFileDialog
    abrir.InitialDirectory = rutaDefault
    abrir.Filter = "Archivos PDF|*.pdf"

    If File.Exists(Path.Combine(rutaDefault, fileDefault)) Then
        'Nombre de archivo que se cargará por defecto, si existe en la ruta
        abrir.FileName = fileDefault
    End If

    If abrir.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile (abrir.FileName) 
    End If
```

Prueba con esto.

Saludos